# HTTP Range Header for Entity lists

Tags: http, rest, entity, range

I have resources like this

```
/entities        # GET, POST
/entities/<id>   # GET, PUT, DELETE
```

GET /entities gets the list of all entities.
Now I want to poll for updates. The case for a single entity is straight forward:

```
GET /entities/2
If-Modified-Since: <http date>
```

The list is tricky. I want the response to be a list of entities, updated or created since a given point in time. I'd intuitively use

```
GET /entities
Range: after <http date>
```

Which is a valid request by HTTP specification http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35.2 . But the spec also mandates a `206 Partial Content` response, which has to include a `Content-Range` header. A `Content-Range` header, in turn, mandates a byte range to be specified http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.16 . This is obviously very inconvenient for my use case.

How would you request a semantic range over HTTP?

Comment: are you sure `Range` can be used with a date?  Section 14.35.1 only discusses byte ranges.

Comment: I agree with @adrift, I can find no reference anywhere in any RFC to `Range: after <http date>` being valid in HTTP/1.1 - if it were, the `Content-Range:` header would be defined to accomodate for it, otherwise the practice would only be half defined.

Comment: The Httpbis spec seems to have a bit more details about non-byte ranges http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p5-range-16

Comment: See also http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From reading section [14.35.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35.1), I would say that the `Range` header is used to request a specific range of bytes from a resource, not to request a group of entities according to when they were modified.

In this case, I believe you should treat your range as a filter and pass the date as a query string parameter:

```
GET /entities?modified-since=<date>
```

Comment: That's what I concluded too. Non byte ranges seem to be allowed for sake of future compatibility, but very underspecified.